# Crystal Reports Java Reporting Component: no texts on diagrams on Linux machine (CentOS)

Tags: java, linux, crystal-reports

I spent 3 days trying to solve this problem without success. So I definitely need somebodys help.

#### The issue

My JSP-based web-application displays couple of reports using Java Reporting Components. Each report contains one or more diagrams. Reports are created using Crystal Reports designer 2008

Everything works fine on my Windows machine, but on Linux production server I don't see any text on diagrams (title, legend and so on).
All other functions - charts themselves, reports, export to PDF etc. - are working.

#### Environment

```
CentOS 5
Tomcat 6
JRC 12.2.211
```

#### What I've already tried:

- To check fonts installed and install windows fonts. It helped me to solve issues with PDF, but still no texts on diagrams
- To check possibility to draw text from Java on this machine. I've just wrote simple class that draws text on image using drawString - it works fine even if I specify font that does not exist
- To change diagram parameters (font, text color, transparency) - without success
- To change Java 2D options - turn OpenGL on/off, offscreen pixmap support, DGA - still no success
- To convert report to higher version (CR 2011) - the same
- To upgrade rendering engine (JRC 12.2.211 -> JRC 12.2.214) - the same.

Does enybody have this issue or ideas how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just found out that text, that is rotated on 90 degrees (on vertical axis) is displayed, that's strange. Also I've tried to turn awt.headless off/on but it didn't help

Comment: Seems that I've won ). Java upgrade from 1.6.17 to 1.6.22 has fixed situation.

Answer (score 0):

Java upgrade from 1.6.17 to 1.6.22 fixes situation.